# Make multiline textbox hold more text (C#, winform)

Tags: c#, winforms

I ran into a little problem, i am trying to filter a rather large list which i copied from another program and pasted into mine. Problem is, theres so much text that only some of it is being pasted into the textbox. The whole list is <256kb.

How do i raise the limit of my in and out textbox to hold ALL of the text? using C# and winform

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx) property of your text boxes to `0` to override the default `32767` character limit:

```
yourTextBox.MaxLength = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure, but I think you can just change the [TextBoxBase.MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx) property. On the linked page it says that the default value is 32767, so that is only 64KB and therefore not enough for your application.

Comment: Technically, that's 32767 *characters*, so it's roughly 64 Kilobytes (or Kibibytes, as we're supposed to say now), not 32. A `char` is 2 bytes wide in .NET.

Comment: yeah that's right, but he talked about his file, and if he does not have many special characters in a utf8 encoded file, a 32KB file will be 32768 characters (or a little more), won't it?

Comment: indeed it would, but the .NET CLR still would have to allocate 64 KB to store it :)

Comment: okay, i just realised he didn't say that the whole file he copies is <256kb, but that he copies a list and the whole list he copies is <256kb. It depends a little on whether he meant 256kb as a file size or as a .NET size. Anyway, it does not really matter, i will change that above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) control instead. There is no character limit on a `RichTextBox`. It is just limited by memory.

Or you could change the `MaxLength` property of the `TextBox`. The maximum value for `MaxLength` is [**4294967295**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or an amount based on available memory, whichever is smaller.